# How to get text at start up of terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

[image: Just as the name shown in this image]

How to get text at start up of terminal  as shown in this image.It should show whenever i open terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `echo ----++++some stuff++++----` to your `~/.bashrc` file.
2. You might want modify [`/etc/motd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/motd.5.html) as well. That message will be shown every time you successfully log in.

Comment: And possibly /etc/issue too.

Comment: or /etc/issue.net for remote login :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the command in your personal `.bashrc` (or `.bash_completion`).

They are run once when you start your terminal.